# Set the time default to 00:00:00 in DB2

Tags: db2

I have a DateTime column (activation_dt) in DB2 table and I want to add 1 day to the date part and my output should be "date 00:00:00".
For example:

How it is - 5/9/2001 03:00:00
how it should be - 5/10/2001 00:00:00

I tried using Concat function but is not working. Date part I am doing as "date(activation_dt +1 day) as new_dt"
Please help how should I achieve this is DB2.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it to a DATE, then TIMESTAMP. Here is the invers, try out the individual parts.

```
values date(timestamp(current date))
```

BTW: What is [CURRENT TIMEZONE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005887.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
VALUES date_trunc('DAY', CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 1 DAY)
```

it will always return the next day 00:00:00 - use activation_dt instead of current timestamp